# Accessing WCF client credentials from the service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, basic-authentication

I have the following call to a WCF service (using basic authentication):

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

client.MyServiceFunction();
```

On the server, I have:

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
    string MyServiceFunction()
    {
         return GetUsernameHere();
    }
}
```

My question is, can I access these credentials in the WCF service and, if so, how?  That is, how would I implement the `GetUsernameHere` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this type of validation to work you must write your own validator for the username and password.

You create a class that inherits from `UserNamePasswordValidator` and specify it in your webconfig like this:

```
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CustomValidator">
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication
            userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=
 "SomeAssembly.MyCustomUserNameValidator, SomeAssembly"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

The custom validator class will look like this:

```
public class MyCustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {

        // Do your username and password check here

    }
}
```

The password is not available outside of the validation portion of WCF so you can only retrieve it using the custom validator.

However if you just want the username, it should be accessible via:

`OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name`

however you may need to specify `<message establishSecurityContext="true" />` as part of your binding's security, and this isn't available on all bindings eg. basicHttpBinding

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <!-- username binding -->
    <binding name="Binding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to validate the username, just access it.  I'm perfectly happy with the validation of the username and password as it is

Comment: You can take the username/password and store them in session in that validator method. The closest I can find to seeing the credentials is inside the `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext`. You may need to include `<message establishSecurityContext="true" />` in your binding security. From what I've read you cannot retrieve the password any other way because it is part of the authentication procedure.

Comment: @NibblyPig Using the code of the question and the custom validator as you propose, my service crashes at startup because it says it needs a certificate. Is it possibile to do it without a certificate?